# url rewrite question

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i want to rewrite the url from the parameter name to directory name:

```
mydomaindotcom/index.php?op=fceebook_aa => 
mydomaindotcom/fceebook_aa/
```

here is my testing code(not working of course):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\\$ index.php?op=$1
```

anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ index.php?op=$1
```

Comment: not working <br>
the following only work without final slash
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?op=$1 # \fceebook_aa <br>